# Unable to write in a canvas tag when it is in a modal dialog in a shiny app in R

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

### Objective

To be able to write in a canvas in a shiny app using a stylus, and then click the *Handwriting to Text* button to convert it to text. For this purpose, I am using the handwriting.js library.

### Problems

1. My shiny app with a `canvas` tag works fine if it is in the main
   page AND the browser is maximized. If I **reduce the browser window
   size**, it becomes difficult to write as you can see here:

   [image]

Note how the position of mouse pointer and the written text is different. With the maximized browser, there is no difference in the pointer and text positions.

2. If I launch it in a **modal dialog**, then I lose the ability to write.

### Working Code

Following code works for the app:

#### app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "styles2.css"),
    tags$script(src = "handwriting.js"),
    tags$script(src = "handwriting.canvas.js"),
    tags$script(src = "handwriting_for_shiny3.js")
  ),
  mod_testing_ui("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_testing_server("test")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### styles2.css

```
.save-button {
  background-color: #00abc5; /* Primary color for save button */
  color: white;
}


.dynamic-canvas-size {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%; /* Ensure the canvas doesn't overflow its container */
  background-color: #F5F5DC; /* Cream color */
  border: 1px solid #000000; /* Black border */
}

.dynamic-canvas-size::before {
        content: '';
        /*position: absolute;*/
        /*top: 0;*/
        /*left: 0;*/
        /*width: 100%;*/
        /*height: 100%;*/
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Dark overlay for lines */
}

.modal-dialog {
  max-width: none !important; /* Override Bootstrap's default max-width for modal dialogs */
}
```

#### handwriting.js and handwriting.canvas.js

You can obtain the code from the official github here: https://github.com/ChenYuHo/handwriting.js

#### handwriting_for_shiny3.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var handwritingCanvas = {};

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("initialize", function(id) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(id + '-handwritingCanvas');
    handwritingCanvas[id] = new handwriting.Canvas(canvas, 3);

    // Enable undo and redo
    handwritingCanvas[id].set_Undo_Redo(true, true);
    console.log("initialize");
  });

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("clearCanvas", function(id) {
    handwritingCanvas[id].erase();
    console.log("erase");
  });

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("undoCanvas", function(id) {
    handwritingCanvas[id].undo();
    console.log("undo");
  });

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("redoCanvas", function(id) {
    handwritingCanvas[id].redo();
    console.log("redo");
  });

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("sendCanvas", function(id) {
    var trace = handwritingCanvas[id].trace;
    var options = {
      language: 'en',
      numOfReturn: 1
    };
    var callback = function(result, err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        Shiny.setInputValue(id + '-recognized_text', result[0]);
      }
    };
    handwriting.recognize(trace, options, callback);
    console.log("send");
  });

  // Resize canvas to match its container size
  function resizeCanvas(id) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(id + '-handwritingCanvas');
    var parent = canvas.parentElement;
    canvas.width = parent.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = parent.clientHeight;
  }

  // Call resizeCanvas function when the window is resized
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    resizeCanvas('canvasID');
  });

  // Call resizeCanvas function initially to set the initial canvas size
  resizeCanvas('canvasID');
});
```

#### Modules

##### mod_testing.R

```
mod_testing_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    mod_handwriting_ui(ns("handwrite"))
  )
}

mod_testing_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      mod_handwriting_server("handwrite")
    }
  )
}
```

##### mod_handwriting.R

```
mod_handwriting_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    # column(
      # width = 4,
      actionButton(ns("clear_canvas"), "Clear Canvas", class = "save-button"),
      actionButton(ns("undo"), "Undo", class = "save-button"),
      actionButton(ns("redo"), "Redo", class = "save-button"),
      actionButton(ns("send"), "Handwriting to text", class = "save-button"),
      textAreaInput(ns("manual_text"), "Enter Text", value = "", width = "1000px"),
      tags$canvas(id = ns("handwritingCanvas"),
                  width = "1200px", height = "600px",
                  # style = "width: vw; height: vh;", # Using viewport units
                  class = "dynamic-canvas-size"
                  )
    # )
  )
}


mod_handwriting_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      ns <- session$ns
      prefix <- ns("")
      nested_id <- sub("-$", "", prefix) # remove the trailing hyphen

      observe({
        session$sendCustomMessage("initialize", message = nested_id)
      })

  observeEvent(input$clear_canvas, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("clearCanvas", message = nested_id)
  })

  observeEvent(input$send, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("sendCanvas", message = nested_id)
  })

  observeEvent(input$undo, {
    print("Undo button clicked")  # Diagnostic output
    session$sendCustomMessage("undoCanvas", message = nested_id)
  })

  observeEvent(input$redo, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("redoCanvas", message = nested_id)
  })

  observeEvent(input$recognized_text, {
    if (!is.null(input$recognized_text)) {
      updateTextAreaInput(session, "manual_text", value = input$recognized_text)
    }
  })


  observe({
    session$sendCustomMessage("initCanvas", message = NULL)
  })

  return(reactive(input$manual_text))

    }
  )
}
```

### Regarding Problem # 2: Canvas in Modal Dialog does not work

#### Modified mod_testing.R

```
mod_testing_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("launch"), "Launch Canvas")
  )
}

mod_testing_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      observeEvent(input$launch, {
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            mod_handwriting_ui(ns("handwrite")),
            title = "Handwrite"
          )
        )
      })

      mod_handwriting_server("handwrite")
    }
  )
}
```

Everything else remains the same, but it does not work.

##### Console Error

I see this error in browser console:

```
jquery.js:4050  jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentElement') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentElement')
    at resizeCanvas (http://127.0.0.1:5976/handwriting_for_shiny3.js:48:25)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:5976/handwriting_for_shiny3.js:59:3)
    at e (http://127.0.0.1:5976/jquery-3.6.0/jquery.min.js:2:30038)
    at t (http://127.0.0.1:5976/jquery-3.6.0/jquery.min.js:2:30340) undefined
S.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.js:4050
jquery.js:4059  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentElement')
    at resizeCanvas (handwriting_for_shiny3.js:48:25)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (handwriting_for_shiny3.js:59:3)
    at e (jquery.js:3766:29)
    at t (jquery.js:3834:12)
shinyapp.ts:442  TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')
    at new handwriting.Canvas (handwriting.canvas.js:19:24)
    at e.<anonymous> (handwriting_for_shiny3.js:6:29)
    at e.<anonymous> (shinyapp.ts:866:40)
    at m (shinyapp.ts:5:1357)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (shinyapp.ts:5:4174)
    at Generator.next (shinyapp.ts:5:2208)
    at f0 (shinyapp.ts:6:99)
    at s (shinyapp.ts:7:194)
    at shinyapp.ts:7:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
(anonymous) @ shinyapp.ts:442
handwriting_for_shiny3.js:48  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentElement')
    at resizeCanvas (handwriting_for_shiny3.js:48:25)
    at handwriting_for_shiny3.js:55:5
    at dispatch (jquery.js:5430:27)
    at v.handle (jquery.js:5234:28)
handwriting_for_shiny3.js:48  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentElement')
    at resizeCanvas (handwriting_for_shiny3.js:48:25)
    at handwriting_for_shiny3.js:55:5
    at dispatch (jquery.js:5430:27)
    at v.handle (jquery.js:5234:28)
handwriting_for_shiny3.js:48  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentElement')
    at resizeCanvas (handwriting_for_shiny3.js:48:25)
    at handwriting_for_shiny3.js:55:5
    at dispatch (jquery.js:5430:27)
    at v.handle (jquery.js:5234:28)
resizeCanvas @ handwriting_for_shiny3.js:48
(anonymous) @ handwriting_for_shiny3.js:55
dispatch @ jquery.js:5430
v.handle @ jquery.js:5234
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the canvas does not exist yet when you launch the app, so the `document.getElementById` does not find it. It exists only once you open the modal. So I would use a reactive value, `run` below, to trigger the initialization when you open the modal. This reactive value is passed as an argument of the module server.

```r
mod_handwriting_server <- function(id, run) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      ns <- session$ns
      prefix <- ns("")
      nested_id <- sub("-$", "", prefix) # remove the trailing hyphen

      observeEvent(run(), {
        session$sendCustomMessage("initialize", message = nested_id)
      })

      ......
```

and:

```r
mod_testing_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      run <- reactiveVal(NULL)
      observeEvent(input$launch, {
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            mod_handwriting_ui(ns("handwrite")),
            title = "Handwrite"
          )
        )
        run(TRUE)
      })

      mod_handwriting_server("handwrite", run)
    }
  )
}
```

*Side note:* You have `observe({session$sendCustomMessage("initCanvas", message = NULL)})` which is not used as far as I can see.

---

## Edit: first problem

Regarding the first problem and the difficulty to write in the modal, that's because `resizeCanvas("canvasID")` is not correct. To fix that, define

```js
  // Resize all canvas to match their container size
  function resizeCanvas() {
    $("canvas").each(function() {
      var parent = this.parentElement;
      this.width = parent.clientWidth;
      this.height = parent.clientHeight;
    });
  }

  // Call resizeCanvas function when the window is resized
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    resizeCanvas();
  });
```

And move the initial call to `resizeCanvas()` in the Shiny message handler:

```js
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("initialize", function(id) {
    resizeCanvas();
    var canvas = document.getElementById(id + '-handwritingCanvas');
    handwritingCanvas[id] = new handwriting.Canvas(canvas, 3);
    // Enable undo and redo
    handwritingCanvas[id].set_Undo_Redo(true, true);
    console.log("initialize");
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand problem # 2 and it is fixed with your answer. Any ideas about problem # 1: difficulty in writing? In the modal dialog, writing is not easy. But without the modal dialog, I can easily write.

Comment: @umairdurrani Sorry no idea.

Comment: @umairdurrani I've tried and this works well inside the modal for me. *But* only after fixing an error in your JavaScript code: `resizeCanvas('canvasID');` should throw an error, because `canvasID` is not the namespace.